# Sencha Touch 2.x : Specifying Listeners in Config - howto

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying to add listeners of the itemtap event in a list view, however, when the list shows up correctly (ie loads from the store), and I tap an item of the list, the listener function is not triggered

Is this because I can't define the listeners inside config: in Ext.define()?

Thanks

```
Ext.define('Volt.view.FeedView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',



    xtype: 'feedViewCard',
    config: {
        iconCls: 'home',
        title: 'FeedView',

        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
        },

        items: [



            {
                xtype: 'list',

                itemTpl: '<div class="list-item-title">{title}</div> <div class="list-item-narrative">{narrative}</div>',

                flex: 1,
                listeners: {

                    itemtap: function(list, index, target, record, e, eOpts ){
                        console.log('List tapped , xtype = ' , list.getXTypes() );
                        debugger;
                    } //however when the list shows up and I tap the items, this function is not triggered

                },
                initialize: function(){
                    console.log('listview initialize');
                    console.log('XType = ',this.getXTypes(),'id = ',this.getId());
                    //console.log('XType = ',list.getXTypes());
                    //debugger;
                    this.setStore(Ext.getStore('Feeds')); 

                }

            }

        ]
    },


});
```

Comment: What version on ST are you using?

Comment: Using ST 2.3    . Thanks

Comment: Interesting... Can you post the code where you are using the FeedView panel?